# Check non-first instance of string in string

Tags: swift, string, nsstring

So, the way I have been getting the instance of a string in another string is by using this String class extension:

```
func indexOf(target: String) -> Int? {

        let range = (self as NSString).range(of: target)

        guard range.toRange() != nil else {
            return nil
        }

        return range.location

    }
```

However, now I am looking for a way to get the nth instance of a string in a string. For example, if I wanted to get index of the 3rd instance of "House" in "Houses on the show House house strange people.". How would I do this?

Comment: Why are you using NSString? String has similar methods.

Comment: I have not found a String method that accomplished the task of finding a string in a string, only a character in a string @maddy

Comment: _to get index of the 3rd instance of "House" in "Houses on the show House house strange people."_ There is no third instance. `"House"` and `"house"` are two different strings.

Comment: _I have not found a String method that accomplished the task of finding a string in a string_ `range(of:options:range:locale:)` works directly on a Swift string.

Comment: @matt the fix to that is converting them both to lower-case then proceeding on with the task.

Comment: @RyanCocuzzo Obviously. Or you can do what I do in my answer below, which is to use the `.caseInsensitive` search option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution which operates directly on the Swift `String`,
without bridging to `NSString` (and without creating temporary substrings):

```
extension String {

    func index(of target: String, instance: Int = 1) -> Int? {
        precondition(!target.isEmpty)
        precondition(instance > 0)

        var found = 0 // Number of occurrences found so far.
        var pos = startIndex // Current search position.
        // Search for next occurrence of `target`.
        while let r = range(of: target, range: pos..<endIndex) {
            found += 1
            // Are we done?
            if found == instance {
                // Distance in # of characters:
                return distance(from: startIndex, to: r.lowerBound)
            }
            // Continue search after this occurrence.
            pos = r.upperBound
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Example:

```
let bStr = "Houses on the show Dr. House's PlayHouse house strange people"
let ls = "House"

if let idx = bStr.index(of: ls, instance: 3) {
    print(idx) // 35
}
```

Comment: "without bridging to NSString" You don't _cast_ to NSString explicitly, but calling `range(of:range:)` calls into Foundation, so there is certainly bridging — it's just implicit. I'm not criticising the implementation, just disputing the claim.

Comment: @matt: You are right of course. What I meant is the explicit bridging and jumping between String vs. NSString indices. The only reason of converting the final range to an Int was because that _seemed_ to be what OP looks for.

Answer (score 1):

I liked Martin R's answer but I find a recursive expression more intuitive. In my implementation, we actually return the Range (as an Optional):

```
extension String {
    typealias SRange = Range<String.Index>
    func range(of target:String, options:String.CompareOptions, nth:Int) -> SRange? {
        func helper(hnth:Int, range:SRange) -> SRange? {
            let r = self.range(of: target, options: options, range: range)
            if let r = r, hnth < nth {
                return helper(hnth:hnth+1, range:r.upperBound..<self.endIndex)
            }
            return r
        }
        return helper(hnth:1, range: self.startIndex..<self.endIndex)
    }
}
```

That returns a Swift Range if the `nth` occurrence of the target string exists, `nil` otherwise. Here's a test:

```
let s = "Houses on the show House house strange people."
let targ = "House"
let r = s.range(of: targ, options: .caseInsensitive, nth: 3)
// now r is an Optional wrapping 25..<30
```

Comment: Never thought about using a recursive approach. This is a very advanced and complete answer. Thank you for sharing this with me.